# json with Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, json

I am using [Jquery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)

I am also using the formatItem. I would like the output to be

```
<json.key: json.value
```

ex

```
Name: Adam
```

However i cant get the json data using the 4th param and i am getting the full json string as the 4th param and one result. How do i use json with this? is another autocomplete recommended? (this one looks pretty good...)

Comment: This article should help point you in the right direction: [http://blog.schuager.com/2008/09/jquery-autocomplete-json-apsnet-mvc.html](http://blog.schuager.com/2008/09/jquery-autocomplete-json-apsnet-mvc.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 2):

i'm using the jQuery UI with this code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
        $("#tbDevices").autocomplete("Static/ui.autocomplete/GetDevices.ashx", {
            width: 160,
            selectFirst: false,
            max: 100,
            autoFill: true,
            matchContains: true,
            highlightItem: true,
            parse: function(data) {
                return $.map(eval(data), function(row) {
                    return {
                        data: row,
                        lable: row.lable, //value being searched for
                        value: row.value //value in text input
                    }
                });
            },
            formatItem: function(row, i, max, term) {
                return "<span style='font-size: 110%;'>" + row.lable + "</span><br/>" + "ID: " + row.value;
            },
            formatResult: function(row, i, max) {
                return row;
            }
        }).result(function(event, item) {
            document.getElementById('#hdnChosenDevice').value = item.value;
            $('#tbDevices').val(item.lable);
        });
    }
```

the ashx file is returning a string with json :

```
[{"lable":"device1","value":"01"},{"lable":"device2","value":"02"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this  is still relevant for this question, but for completeness' sake I'll include the standalone jQuery autocompleter plugin that is still around (and actively developed):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the json format because its a standard. Since its hard to construct it at server side , my suggestion is to go for a JSON api .
You need not worry about the formatting 
Also make sure to set the response as "application/json"